# python debugging point equivalent to Perl $DB::single=1

Tags: python, debugging, emacs

I am a Perl programmer learning Python. I am writing my code in emacs debugging with `python -m pdb script.py` using Python 2.7.3.

I would like to know what is the python equivalent to in Perl adding a `$DB::single=1;1;` to a specific line of python code, so that when running the debugger, it will stop there, even if it's a different source code file from where the execution started (e.g. a line of code in a library being used by `script.py`).

Any ideas?

EDITED: after looking at `pdb.set_trace()` or `ipdb.set_trace()`, I consider them good solutions but not 100% identical to the behaviour of `$DB::single=1;1;`. This is, I would like the breakpoint to be on the set_trace line, instead of the next line. This is accomplished in Perl's `$DB::single=1;` by adding another statement in the same line: `1;`, which makes it `$DB::single=1;1;`.

Using `set_trace()`, I get the breakpoint at the line after the statement, even if I add `1;` after it. Still not fully understanding how Python treats multi-statement lines in comparison to Perl.

Anybody?

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, did you try setting breakpoint using `C-x SPACE` (in the python buffer), note you will need to have pdb running for this to work.

Comment: Why does it matter that the breakpoint is on the next line?  Why must the functionality be identical to Perl's?

Comment: jpkotta, it is cosmetic, but I want a static breakpoint that actually makes the debugger stop there, not at the next statement. Eg, if you have 1000 lines worth of comments before the next statement, the distance between your breakpoint and the next statement is annoying.

Comment: But the breakpoint itself is not the code you are debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python comes with debugger called [`pdb`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html). To stop a script at given point in code put the following

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Since you are using emacs, you would may want to try out the command `pdb` provided by `gud.el` (**correction**: You do not need to preload 'python-mode' to run `pdb`, thanks @Andreas Röhler for correction) . Start it by `pdb name_of_script.py`, then you can set breakpoint from emacs by pressing <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd> at the line you want to set breakpoint at.  I recommend you to use `menu-bar` to explore the commands provided by the debugger (`GUD`). You can also use the usual `pdb` commands in the `*gud-pdb*` buffer started by emacs.

Comment: To be precise: pdb is not provided by python-mode, it's an interactive autoloaded Lisp function in `gud.el'. Which means: you can run a program from pdb at any time, no python-mode preload needed.

Answer (score 6):

Is the following satisfying your needs ?

```
import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

just write it somewhere in your code and run your script with `python script.py`.

you need the ipython debugger ([ipython](http://ipython.org) is an enhanced python interpreter):

```
pip install ipdb
```

**edit:** did you know that if you run `M-x pdb RET pdb myscript.py RET`, you'll have a pdb prompt and emacs will track the source code in another buffer, but it doesn't stop where you defined `ipdb.set_trace()` ?

**Virtual Env ?**

if you use virtual envs, you have a couple of options. I recommand installing `virtualenvwrapper` from ELPA and run `M-x venv-workon`.

Comment: I use `M-x pdb RET python -m pdb myscript.py RET`.